# What's proper touchpad driver for new Asus ( R540SC, Windows 8.1 )?

Tags: windows-8, drivers, touchpad, asus-laptop

I've been researching a lot these week to find drivers for my Asus R540SC. I installed Windows 8.1 on FreeDos software ( Initial software on laptop ) and it had no drivers at all, so i needed to install them manually: I have installed all of them except the touchpad driver.

So after all the research these were the steps i have taken:

1. Install chipset driver ( newest Intel(R) INF ). - Successful
2. Install Asus ATK driver ( newest one. ) - Successful
3. Installing touchpad driver - Failed:

   - Installing smart gesture touchpad driver for my specific laptop model from Asus support ( [R540SC](http://www.asus.com/supportonly/R540SC/HelpDesk_Download/) ) -- OS selection was for Windows 10 only, in process 
     of installing got this error:

   > There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run
   >   as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support
   >   and personnel or package vendor.

   - Installing smart gesture drivers for Windows 8.1 ( Laptop's model Version is not specified ) -- I got the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmCOZ.png) as excepted ( I think it's Windows problem ).
   - Trying other drivers: Elantech, Synaptics ( Got error on both, that device was not found ).

---

Notes:

- I don't have 'Mice' section under device manager. ( How can i fix it? )
- I neither have 'Trackpad' section on Windows mouse settings.
- If you wonder how do i install drivers without mouse, i use keyboard mouse from windows ease access.

Device Manager Picture:

[image]

(Please comment if you want me to dropdown anything from it).

---

It's very disappointing that Asus have their touchpad drivers for R540SC on Windows 8.1, but i have seen some using touchpad with it, What could the problem be? Is it Windows or Asus? How could i find a normal touchpad/trackpad driver for my Asus?

Comment: I'm confused what you mean by you installed Windows 8.1 on Free-Dos software? Also, here is a [direct link](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/DriversForWin8.1/SmartGesture/SmartGesture_Win81_64_VER225.zip?_ga=1.168160033.1648684628.1477504918) to a touchpad driver for Windows 8.1 64 bit. See if that works for you. You can find more driver options for the touchpad [here](http://www.asus.com/support/Download/3/589/0/1/41/)

Comment: @DrZoo I'm sorry, i meant `FreeDos`. The laptop's initial software was FreeDos and i installed Windows 8.1 on it. I'm going to try that driver asap.

Comment: @DrZoo Tried installing latest one and got the [error](http://i.imgur.com/948jE9O.png). Is it windows?

Comment: That's strange, Asus usually used Elantech touchpads in the past. Please open *Device Manager*, find your touchpad under *Mice and other pointing devices* and in its properties on *Details* tab you'll find property *Hardware Ids*. Please post it here.

Comment: Hello @gronostaj as i mentioned in notes, i don't have `Mice` section in device manager, what's the reason? do i have to install something? or is device not connected?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your *Device Manager*?

Comment: @gronostaj [Here](http://i.imgur.com/B93ljnB.png)

Comment: @gronostaj By the way is that uncommon not to have mice in device manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Touchpads are typically connected through internal PS/2 port, so they should work without dedicated drivers with only some extra features being unavailable. The fact that your touchpad doesn't work and you have no mice in *Device Manager* suggests that touchpad is broken or physically disconnected from the motherboard. That would also explain why Windows 8.1 drivers didn't install.

You can attempt to confirm this by booting any LiveCD operating system, for example [Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). You can prepare bootable DVD or flash disk using this laptop or some other one. If touchpad won't work there, then you can assume hardware fault with reasonable confidence.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and is there anything to fix this problem? The laptop is brand new, maybe there is no connection to motherboard?

Comment: If it's new, then ask for replacement. Accessing touchpad connector will void your warranty.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i had a doubt about the problem, but was not confident about it, I hope that's the only reason for this problem.